# How to instantiate AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

```
package com.markana.yamba;

import winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter;
import winterwell.jtwitter.TwitterException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StatusActivity2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private static final String TAG= "StatusActivity";
    EditText editText;
    Button updateButton;
    TextView textCount;
    Twitter twitter;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.status);
        //Finds views
        editText =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        updateButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
        updateButton.setOnClickListener(this);



        twitter=new Twitter("student","password");
        twitter.setAPIRootUrl(("http://yamba.marakana.com/api"));   

    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String status=editText.getText().toString();
        new PostToTwitter().execute(status);
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick");
    }

    class PostToTwitter extends AsyncTask<String,Integer, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... statuses) {

            try{
            Twitter.Status status=twitter.updateStatus(statuses[0]);
            return status.text;
            }
            catch(TwitterException e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Failed to post";
            }
        }


        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...values)
        {
               super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            Toast.makeText(StatusActivity2.this,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
        }
    }





}
```

i get two exceptions relating to Async task

thats what i did. it tells me that i have a problem when i run the background worker!!

```
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:447)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:157)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter$Status.<init>(Twitter.java:659)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.updateStatus(Twitter.java:3231)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.updateStatus(Twitter.java:3161)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at com.markana.yamba.StatusActivity2$PostToTwitter.doInBackground(StatusActivity2.java:60)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at com.markana.yamba.StatusActivity2$PostToTwitter.doInBackground(StatusActivity2.java:1)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     ... 4 more
```

it should pop a message in the end.. as you can see in the method onClick!

Comment: what's the problem here, you seem to be creating the task on onClick rite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that the

```
Toast.makeText(StatusActivity2.this,res..
```

fails, as the context you pass in is not valid.

Try to pass in the `Context` in the Constructor of `PostToTwitter`, store it locally and then use this instance when creating the `Toast`.

See e.g. [here](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/TweetListActivity.java#L277) for the call, [here](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/TweetListActivity.java#L334) for the Constructor and [here](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/TweetListActivity.java#L417) for the onPostExecute

Comment: it still crashes. i created a new constructor in PostToTwitter and passed it a reference to the outer class. then put the reference in the Toast (context, result..    it still tells me that there is a problem in the doInBackground

Comment: Is the above all you get from logcat? No additional lines before or above? Die the crash message change with your latest change? Also why don't you just hook up a debugger and step through the doInBackground() etc. methods?

Comment: i updated what i got from LogCat. i got 2 exception. now i am checking with the debugger. although this is the first time, i debug android code

Comment: You are running into an internal issue of the used twitter library. jTwitter is trying to parse the return value from Twitter and fails at it. I guess at this point you should contact the devlopper of that library. Or (as the source for it exists) try to fix it there.

Comment: IllegalArgumentException
thats the exception that is being thrown just after the doInBackground exception. i looked into the java api and it says "Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument. " so i guess, the AsyncTask interfaces methods get passed invalid parameters. am i right? , and you are saying it isnt my fault?

Comment: No, not your fault: See `at java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:157)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter$Status.<init>(Twitter.java:659)` -- the library tries to parse the 'created_at' from the return as date and fails as the thing it passes into Date(String) can not be recognized as date. Your AsyncTask itself is ok as it is.

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(String result)
  {
   Toast.makeText(statusActivity, "Moo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    well, i think that Orielly Learning Android is out of date or something, and is useless. it wasted my time. dont buy it
  }... i changed the string result to "Moo" and it does work.. so it is an invalidArugument issue

Answer (score 1):

Twitter.java:659

are you using some date creation here ? looks like you are parsing a string to date object and string is not in the date format specified.

below is ur problem part. nothing to do with task creation i guess.what format is 04-20 09:21:32.553

i guess it should be somewat like mm-dd-yy hh:mm:ss.nnn or some other standard format

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:447)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:157)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter$Status.<init>(Twitter.java:659)
04-20 09:21:32.553: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.updateStatus(Twitter.java:3231)`

Comment: Thank  you for the comment, i am new to all debugging in Android so i didnt know

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand properly: update your screen in the onPostExecute method. You might want to have a member variable of your activity holding the current task. The in your onClick function, simply check if a task is already running before creating a new one.

Also, don't forget to remove the click listener when you destroy your activity, else you will leak memory.

```
protected void onDestroy() {
  updateButton.setOnClickListener(null);
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: do you have any evidence of such memory leaks?

Comment: i tested it again. it actually goes to the doInBackground.. it wrote to me "failed to send" (if you look thats what i put in my clause case). it seems to me that it gets overwhelmed by 2 or more conflicting threads

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with AsyncTask or Context. The below line is failing which is doing some date parsing. Can you try calling below in a main thread without AsyncTask and see if it is working?.

Twitter.Status status=twitter.updateStatus(statuses[0]);